# Why do we use "the" in " He thinks that the richer he becomes, the happier he will be."?

Tags: articles, adjectives

"He thinks that the richer he becomes, the happier he will be."

Why do we use "the richer" in this sentence?

Comment: It's a "set phrase" construction, most commonly found in ***the more the merrier*** today (which dates from 1530 as [*“The more the merrier; the fewer, the better fare” (meaning “with fewer there would be more to eat”), an observation that made its way into numerous proverb collections*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=9QuEiIMaBt0C&pg=PA298&lpg=PA298&dq=the+fewer+the+better+idiom&source=bl&ots=fHH-sHxO7g&sig=XZMANb2gfx_T5xE1AjQLRgVgRhs&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false).)

Comment: ...fixed structure ***the [comparative1] the [comparative2]*** equates to the observation that [comparative1] and [comparative2] are *positively correlated* (if one goes up, so does the other).

Answer (score 2):

As others have observed in comments, "the 'X'-er, the 'Y'-er" is a set phrase to be learned whole, rather than dissected and reasoned out in pieces (e.g.: what is the meaning of the "**the**" parts?)

However, I do think you can make *some* sense of it by considering the definite articles ("**the**") as naming a specific increment of increase in each of the adjectives "X" and "Y", and setting them equal to each other. In other words, "**the** richer" isn't just "richer" by an indefinite amount, but richer by a specific amount, (**the** richer) and "**the** happier" is happier by the same amount (never mind the units here; this isn't pseudo-physics - it's pseudo-math.) So, X + "the" increment of X = Y + "the same" increment of Y. Not for everyone, but it works for me. Please let me know how off-base I am, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Because that is the form that such expressions take in English.

Somebody has commented, mentioning the idiomatic expression "the more, the merrier". But this is abbreviated. The structure normally has full clauses, as in:

> The more he shouts at them, the more obstinate they will become.

"Why" questions about language hardly ever have answers other than "because that's how we say it".

Comment: Somewhere in there one might mention comparatives, mightn't one?